Determining rent epoch
Is there a way to determine preferably on chain when the rent for an account was last paid? If not, is there a way to do so off-chain?

Technically, this is stored in the rent-epoch on the AccountInfo struct: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/7c12f038dd7829ce3216bdd91b5de9d24631e279/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L29
So you can get it with a simple program:
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

solana_program::entrypoint!(process_instruction);

/// Instruction processor
pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Create an iterator to safely reference accounts in the slice
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    msg!("{}", account_info.rent_epoch);
    Ok(())
}

But the rent_epoch doesn't mean anything anymore, since rent has been removed from all networks.

Do you mean if we have sol balance > Rent-exempt minimum, then the sol never consumed or expire, as long as its in the account?

That's correct, and if the sol balance is less than the rent-exempt minimum, then the transaction will just fail

Do you mean if the sender's balance is less than the rent-exempt minimum then tx will fail, or receiver's, or either ? It seems it's impossible to make the balance less than the rent-exempt minimum unless become 0?

That's all correct, an account must have at least the rent-exempt minimum, or 0 lamports.
